# python tweeter api search any tweets

Tags: python, api, twitter, python-requests, tweepy

I'd like to search tweet without a matching word but only with a condition. i.e. search all tweet that has hastags. I'm using twitter api according to the doc [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/introduction). I built my query like so:

endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?query=has%3Ahashtags"

And I received an error:
"message": "There were errors processing your request: is/has/lang cannot be used as a standalone operator (at position 1)"

How do I search query any tweets that contains a hashtag?
Thanks.

Comment: Your error says *is/has/lang cannot be used as a standalone operator*. You should use the has: operator with something else. Therefore, you cannot just search for tweets using a single `has:`, which means you cannot search for tweets that include any hashtag.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the error message. My question is if there's a way to work around this error and still query by condition only, i.e. a query that return any tweet that has a hashtag of any tag. Is there a keyword "any" or "*" that I can put in the query so has:hashtag is not a stand-alone operator?

Comment: Seems like there's no workaround, unfortunately.

Comment: hi there  KY did you ever find a workaround?